# How to prevent double thickness borders at overlap?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If you have:

```
<Grid >
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

and put a border of thickness 1 into each grid, you will get double thickness on the border between the grid rows. Is the only way to deal with this to specify the thickness on each edge of the border or is there some control that will create borders around the grid for each column without having double thickness?

Currently attempting it with this:

```
                    <Border  
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      Margin="19,0,0,0"  
                      Background="LightGray"
                      >
                      <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                      <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        x:Name="TreeViewHeaderTextBox" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="Time"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        />


                      <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="X"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        />

                      <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Text="O"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        />

                    </Grid>
                  </Viewbox>
                </Border>
```

However, I started making changes to the old code so this isn'ta  really good example of the double borders. However, I am also getting double borders from this template.

```
              <Border Name="Bd"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
              </Border>
```

as each item ends up with a double thickness border where it touches the next item.

edit 2: After reading the comments I realized I probably should not have a border defined on the datatemplate for the control and instead just set the border through the control and change the template on the controltemplate. May be getting double borders from that.

Comment: Please post how you are currently setting the border thickness.

Comment: I had borders inside the grid that i was changing the border thickness of. Perhaps I just need one for the outermost grid and it will wrap each item. That makes sense. that or maybe there is a grid border thickness property. I will go look into it

Comment: Have you ever heard the expression XAML is worth a thousand words?

Comment: @Blam Only if it has a closing tag! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap grid in a border element and set the thickness I believe that puts a border between each grid item and avoids your doubled border - trying to test this now.

Comment: this makes sense. I should have thought of this. I just found it strange and moved on. I will test it now

Comment: Hope it helps - I could not find a project I could test on quickly and had to move on for a bit. If you still don't have success I will try and dig something up. I do know I have seen it done with a single border setting.

Answer (score 2):

Thickness can be set to ="left, top, right, bottom", which means you can set the overlapping parts to half.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0.5" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    <Border BorderThickness="1,0.5" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Border BorderThickness="1,0.5,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"  Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```